# Using $http.get to retrieve a single record

Tags: javascript, php, sql, angularjs

I have a few functions in a PHP file that are to write and request data from a server database.  The requests for these php functions come from a js file. My first function to write to the server works, but I am at a roadblock with no errors in my console to go on with for retrieving a single record.

Currently, I believe I have correctly pulled data, as I can see it in the console log, but the data does not seem to assign to the variables.

My PHP file

```
    switch($_GET['action']){
case 'writeInvoice':
        writeInvoice();
        break;
case 'fetchInvoice':
        fetchInvoice($_GET['num']);
        break;
}

function fetchInvoice($num){

$fqry = "SELECT customerName,
                dealerName,
                billTo,
                billStart,
                contractTerms,
                item,
                itemPrice,
                quantity,
                sharePercent,
                cost
                FROM invoice
                WHERE idInvoice = '{$num}'";


$qry = new Query($fqry,__LINE__,__FILE__);
$result = json_encode($qry->fetch_array());
print_r($result);


return $result;
}
```

My js/angular code

```
    $scope.editInvoice  = function($param){

    $http.get('DealerRec/writeInvoice.php?num='+$param+'&action=fetchInvoice', $scope.list)
        .success(function(data,status,headers,config){console.log("Data Taken"); console.log(data);
         fetchData = data; 
          $scope.list.idInvoice     = $param;
    $scope.list.customerName  = fetchData.customerName;
    $scope.list.dealerName    = fetchData.dealerName;
    $scope.list.billTo        = fetchData.billTo;
    $scope.list.billStart     = fetchData.billStart;
    $scope.list.item          = fetchData.item;
    $scope.list.price         = fetchData.price;
    $scope.list.qty           = fetchData.qty;
    $scope.list.contractTerms = fetchData.contractTerms;
    $scope.list.per           = fetchData.per;
    $scope.list.cost          = fetchData.cost;

 })
        .error(function(data,status,headers,config){ console.log("Data Not Taken"); });



    CustomModal.setOption(2);
};
```

My goal is to retrieve an Invoice from the database by invoice ID #, and store the field that I may be able to view and write over it.

My console is showing this, when I call the function on say, entry 12

```
Data Taken

(
    [num] => 12
    [action] => fetchInvoice
 )
                                          {"customerName":"SomeCustomer","dealerName":"SomeDealer","billTo":"Customer","billStart":"2015-06-10","contractTerms":"Billing Software    Terms","item":"SomeItem","itemPrice":"150.00","quantity":"20","sharePercent":"75","cost":"15.00"}
```

When the function executes, in its last line it opens a modal, where the data is set/editable.

Answer (score 0):

The following part is wrong for sure:

```
fetchData = $http.get('DealerRec/writeInvoice.php?num='+$param+'&action=fetchInvoice', $scope.list)
    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){console.log("Data Taken"); console.log(data); })
    .error(function(data,status,headers,config){console.log("Data Not Taken"); });
```

You cannot assign the result(s) of `$http` service to `fetchData` like this. You need to do this in the success callback:

```
$http.get('DealerRec/writeInvoice.php?num='+$param+'&action=fetchInvoice',$scope.list)
    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        console.log("Data Taken"); 
        console.log(data); 
        fetchData = data; // this is what you have to do
    })
    .error(function(data,status,headers,config){ 
        console.log("Data Not Taken"); 
    });
```

Comment: I actually discovered this a moment ago, however it doesn't seem to be assigning still.

Comment: Well, you need to assign the results to `$scope.list` also in the callback.

Comment: Alright, I've done that, but still nothing.  I wonder if calling CustomModal has something to do with the timing?

Comment: Have you added it also inside the callback?

Comment: I did.  Nothing is displaying when I have 

    <pre>list = {{list}}</pre>

Though.

I also tried separating the CustomModal call, but thats not the issue either

Comment: try {{ list | json }}, otherwise I have no idea what could be wrong.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be it, but really I appreciate your input!